# ECW support on QGIS 3.22, GDAL (Mac OS 11.2.3 Big Sur)

Tags: gdal, vrt, ecw, virtual-raster

I'm having trouble making virtual raster layers of .ecw files. I can load them into QGIS 3.22 but I can't seem to use `buildvrt` on them. I wonder why since GDAL `warp` seems to work on these files if I want to convert the resolution of an individual tile, for example.

I've found some threads of people installing extra drivers to get it to work on Mac, but I have a lot of trouble understanding the steps I need to take.

Has anyone done this recently and can walk me through this like I know nothing at all?

Many of the threads I found are from a few years and versions of Q/GDAL ago, too.

The weird thing is that I am nearly certain I successfully built a VRT on 3.10 A Coruna, but I've downgraded to no avail.

As far as workarounds - I can't convert to .tif and build a VRT as I don't have enough disc space to make it happen.

Comment: If you convert ECW info TIFF as `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=jpeg -co photometric=ycbcr input.ecw output.tif` the result will not be much bigger than ECW. If you use `-of cog` you will get also the overviews automatically but overviews add about 25% to the file size.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I want to make a VRT of the ECWs to save space.

Comment: You could move the ECW files into a backup place after conversion if you dare not to delete them. But I do not know any fundamental reason why buildvrt would not work for ECW files. Can you convert one file with `gdal_translate -of VRT input.ecw output.vrt?` Can you use gdalbuildvrt for just one input ECW?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.